# What is the angle between the vectors?

Tags: vectors

$\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}$ are unit vectors such that  $(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b})\cdot \{(\overrightarrow{2a}+\overrightarrow{3b}) \times (\overrightarrow{3a}-\overrightarrow{2b})\} = 0$ then the angle between $a$ & $b$ is

The options included $0$, indeterminate etc...

Firstly, is there a geometrical interpretation that will help solve this question?

Secondly, calculating the cross product just gives another vector which does not seem to be useful.Do you have some hints?

Comment: the angle between the two vectors can be found either by the dot product or the cross product

Comment: "such that ....", I guess you missed something there, OP.

Comment: vector product? cosx = a.b/(mod a X mod b)

Comment: @bigbang That is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Bhavik Couldn't simplify. Tried taking the cross product. No result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we expand it.

$$ (2a + 3b) \times (3a - 2b) = 6 a \times a -4 a \times b + 9 b \times a - 6 b \times b = -13 a \times b $$

where the last equality holds because $a \times a = 0$ and the same for $b$. So, the original equations reads

$$ -13 (a+b) \cdot (a \times b) = 0 \iff (a+b) \cdot (a \times b) = 0 \iff a \cdot (a \times b) = -b \cdot (a \times b) $$

Using the fact that $c \cdot d = |c| |d| \cos(c,d)$ for any vectors $c$ and $d$, we see that the above is equivalent to

$$ |a| |a\times b| \cos(a,a\times b) = - |b| |a\times b|\cos(b, a\times b). $$

As bigbang pointed out, $\cos(a,a\times b) = 0 = \cos(b, a\times b)$. This means $a$ and $b$ can be chosen freely and the angle is indeterminate.

Comment: Isn't the angle between $a, a \times b = \pi/2$? the cos of that would be zero, wouldn't it? Pretty sure the answer should be indeterminate. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right bigbang. Sorry, I was too quick. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @bigbang Exactly. It should be indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer by Philipp seems to be wrong to me. We can see it both intuitively and mathematically.

We know that for any two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, $$\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 \text{ lies in the same plane as of } v_1 \text{ and } v_2$$
Hence, the two vectors $(2a + 3b)$ and $(3a - 2b)$ lie in the plane of the vectors $a$ and $b$.

Therefore, the vector obtained using the cross product must be perpendicular to the plane of $a$ and $b$.

Now, we know that $a + b$ also lies in the same plane as of $a$ and $b$. Hence, the two vectors $a+b$ and $(2a + 3b)\times(3a - 2b)$ must be perpendicular which automatically makes the dot product zero.

Hence, the above condition is true for any two vectors implying that the angle between them is **indeterminate**.

---

Mathematically, as Phillip went ahead, we will simplify the product to get that $$-13 (a+b)\cdot (a \times b) = 0 \implies a \cdot (a\times b) + b \cdot (a \times b) = 0$$ which is again, true for any two vectors $a$ and $b$.